# Control-C kills Ipython in git bash on Windows 7

Tags: git, ipython, sigint

After so many years cruising on Linux, I am back on a freaking Windows environment.
I use Ipython, and I launch it in git bash.
It would be hard for me to use something else, since the environment is configured to use this at my office.

So, when I launch Ipython, and I mistakenly launch an infinite loop, or some bad code that takes ages to execute, I use ctrl-c.

This kills Ipython, and it's pretty annoying. I did not find any way to circumvene this or another key that would do the trick.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: btw, it's the same with python, not only ipython

Answer (score 5):

I actually found an elegant solution. I put this in my .bashrc:

```
alias p="trap '' 2; ipython;trap 2;"
```

that way, ctrl-c signal (which code is 2) gets trapped before launching it, and untrapped when exiting ipython.